# ACF query with variable in value

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I try to do a request with a variable to display all interview of a event.
So in my query i ask all post where "evenement_associe" egual the id of the page. But i don't know why, the query is empty.
The image is the group field of article.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba3Em.png)

```
<?php
            // args
            $id_eventz = get_the_ID();
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'meta_key' => 'evenement_associe',
                'meta_value' => $id_eventz
            );


            // query
            $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

            ?>

            <?php
            if ($the_query) {
                ?>
                <?php if ($the_query->have_posts()): ?>
                    <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post() ?>
                        <?php
                        $value_link=get_field('evenement_associe');
                        $id_article=get_the_ID();
                        $title_article=get_the_title($id_article);
                        ?>

                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <?php

                            ?>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php else: echo 'Aucun article encore réalisé pour cet évènement.'?>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php wp_reset_query();     // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
                //
            } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what is wrong you could check SQL query by using:

```
var_dump($the_query->request);
```

Are you sure there is any post with meta `evenement_associe` that value is `$id_eventz`? Check in database by query:

```
SELECT post.* FROM wp_posts AS post
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS meta
ON post.ID = meta.post_id
WHERE meta.meta_key = 'evenement_associe' AND meta.meta_value = ID_THAT_YOU_LOOKING_FOR
```

Comment: i have this SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_sites_dev_2_posts.ID FROM wp_sites_dev_2_posts INNER JOIN wp_sites_dev_2_postmeta ON ( wp_sites_dev_2_posts.ID = wp_sites_dev_2_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( ( wp_sites_dev_2_postmeta.meta_key = 'evenement_associe' AND wp_sites_dev_2_postmeta.meta_value = '10280' ) ) AND wp_sites_dev_2_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_sites_dev_2_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_sites_dev_2_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_sites_dev_2_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_sites_dev_2_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_sites_dev_2_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10

Comment: Did you try execute in db my query (change 'wp_' to 'wp_sites_dev_2_')?

Comment: i havent access to the db.

Comment: try do it by wpdb: "global $wpdb; var_dump($wpdb->get_results(your_query));"